# Does using less projects result in faster build time?

Tags: visual-studio, optimization, build

My solution has fifteen projects. Am I likely to see much of speed gain if I were to reduce it to, say, five? Or else have the same number of projects but move them into multiple solutions?

I'm specifically talking about starting up an ASP.net website.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it depends.  If you just build one project rather than build the whole solution, then it doesn't matter.  But obviously if you have a solution with 15 projects it will take longer to build the solution than one with 10 projects.  What is really your concern here?  It takes x amount of time to build y number of projects, and nothing is going to change that.

Comment: I suspect the slow part is IIS Express starting up and loading dlls.

Comment: Bit of a lazy answer. Let's be more scientific about it.

Answer (score 0):

There's a way for you to answer this question for yourself.

`git branch` from your original solution, and condense all of your projects together. It should be easy enough to drag & drop folders to a single project. There should be core code in one project of its own, and then separate projects for things that require a special project type, such as an Azure Service Fabric service (each service requires its own project) or a Test project.

Now pop open a command line and navigate to your solution's directory. `timeit` is the Windows command line tool to time a command, you can get it [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17657). Using `timeit msbuild MySolution.sln`, you'll be able to measure the build time of the solution. Make sure to clean the solution first (through VS is easy, but msbuild probably lets you do it too). If `timeit` doesn't work, you can do the same with PowerShell's `Measure-Command`.

Now go back to your original project branch and do the same command, `timeit msbuild MySolution.sln`. Compare the difference and let us know! I'm interested in the answer myself but don't have the time to run through a good experiment like this yet.